# Let $a_n=\frac {(n+1)^{100}}{e^\sqrt n} $ for $ n\ge 1$ then the sequence $(a_n)_n$ is ? convergent?

Tags: calculus, limits

i am finding 
$$lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=\frac {(n+1)^{100}}{e^\sqrt n} 
$$
by applying L'hospital rule $\frac {200(n+1)^{99}\sqrt n}{{e^\sqrt n}} $ and applying it doesn't solve it because it will always  give $\infty/\infty$ form.basically i want to check that this series is convergent .

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Hence $e^x \geq \frac{x^{300}}{300!}$

Now use this fact with $x = \sqrt{n}$.

Note that the above inequality gives us the fact that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-x} x^n = 0$$ for any exponent $n$.

Answer (score 1):

You can  consider ln$(a_n)$.This is convergent to ${-\infty}$.So the sequence is convergent to $0$